# unable to install software due to pyconfig.h missing

Tags: 14.04, python

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with python 2.7.6 and the `pyconfig.h` is missing.

After updating at the last it says the header file missing.

The command is

```
sudo pip install <software>
```

How could it be solved?

Answer (score 4):

The file is part of various packages:

```
libpython2.7-dbg: /usr/include/python2.7_d/pyconfig.h
libpython2.7-dbg: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7_d/pyconfig.h
libpython2.7-dev: /usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h
libpython2.7-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7/pyconfig.h
libpython3.4-dbg: /usr/include/python3.4dm/pyconfig.h
libpython3.4-dbg: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4dm/pyconfig.h
libpython3.4-dev: /usr/include/python3.4m/pyconfig.h
libpython3.4-dev: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python3.4m/pyconfig.h
pypy-dev: /usr/lib/pypy/include/pyconfig.h
```

In your case, I would say, you need

```
sudo apt-get install libpython2.7-dev
```